# IPv6 only works incoming and localy on FreeBSD 8.4

Tags: networking, ipv6, freebsd

I am running FreeBSD 8.4 and have trouble with IPv6.

I can connect to my server from outside, connect locally to my jails. But from the server I cannot connect to the outside world.
When I ping6 to ipv6.google.com, it tells me it send xx packets, received 0, 100% loss.

I am not sure in what direction I should search, any advise is appreciated.

(I recently upgraded to 8.4 from 8.1. Since I do not use IPv6 much, I cannot be certain if it worked before, though I am quite sure it did.)

In rc.conf I have this:

```
ipv6_enable="YES" 
rtsold_enable="YES"
ipv6_defaultrouter="xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::1"
ipv6_ifconfig_em0="xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::2"
ipv6_ifconfig_em0_alias0="xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::106"
ipv6_ifconfig_em0_alias1="xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::107"
ipv6_static_routes="myroute1"
ipv6_route_myroute1="xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::0/64 xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::1"
```

In resolv.conf:

```
search lxs.biz
# dns of uplink
nameserver [xxxx:yyyy:zzz::23]
nameserver [xxxx:yyyy:zzz::24]
#openDNS
nameserver [2620:0:ccc::2]
nameserver [2620:0:ccd::2]
```

output of netstat -rn

```
Internet6: 
Destination                       Gateway                  Flags      Netif Expire
::/96                             ::1                     UGRS        lo0 => 
default                           xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::1       UGS         em0 
::1                               link#12                 UH          lo0 
::ffff:0.0.0.0/96                 ::1                     UGRS        lo0 
xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::/64               link#5                  U           em0 
xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::2                 link#5                  UHS         lo0 
xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::106               link#5                  UHS         lo0 
xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::107               link#5                  UHS         lo0 
fe80::/10                         ::1                     UGRS        lo0 
fe80::%em0/64                     link#5                  U           em0 
fe80::225:90ff:fe10:7e84%em0      link#5                  UHS         lo0 
fe80::%lo0/64                     link#12                 U           lo0 
fe80::1%lo0                       link#12                 UHS         lo0 
ff01::%em0/32                     fe80::225:90ff:fe10:7e84%em0  U           em0 
ff01::%lo0/32                     ::1                           U           lo0 
ff02::/16                         ::1                           UGRS        lo0 
ff02::%em0/32                     fe80::225:90ff:fe10:7e84%em0  U           em0 
ff02::%lo0/32                     ::1                           U           lo0
```

Comment: If you can connect to your server from outside *via IPv6*, then your routes are probably okay. If your routes are okay and you can't ping ipv6.google.com by name, then your DNS settings may be the problem. Can you ping6 any known public IPv6 address *by address, not name*?

Comment: It's difficult to tell whether your setup is correct since you have obfuscated everything useful. But, check the actual IPv6 address of your gateway with `ping6 -c 1 -I em0 ff02::2`. The gateway will respond to the ping from its IPv6 address, if it is up.

Comment: The gateway does respond to ping.

Comment: Actualy, I cannot connect to ::2, I was mistaken. All the aliases are reachable though.

Comment: I am going to take a fresh look at the problem. I need to do some extra testing from inside the jails that run on the aliases as well.

Comment: "ping6 2a00:1450:4013:c00::66" has the same result as "ping6 ipv6.google.com", not ping respone.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the ::2 address in the rc.conf with ::100, and than reboot once more did the trick.

I also removed the line

```
rtsold_enable="YES"
```

I removed it because I added it while I already had the problem.

This is now my rc.conf:

```
ipv6_enable="YES" 
ipv6_defaultrouter="xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::1"
ipv6_ifconfig_em0="xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::100"
ipv6_ifconfig_em0_alias0="xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::106"
ipv6_ifconfig_em0_alias1="xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::107"
ipv6_static_routes="myroute1"
ipv6_route_myroute1="xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::0/64 xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::1"
```

If anyone knows why this works, while ::2 did not, I am very curious.